# How to stop excel from changing data format to dates?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a question that I haven't been able to find a script for. Is there a VBA script or can someone create a script that will stop Excel 2010 from changing the data, such as 1-2 to 2-Jan?

I recorded a macro that changed all the rows and columns of the first three tabs to the Text format and saved it as a personal workbook in the `XLSTART` folder. So, whenever I create a new excel file, the personal workbook is loaded by default.

But, whenever I click on a new tab and how ever many additional tabs, the format is not replicated. Only the first three sheets has the Text format. My question is, is the a script that will automatically keep the data as I input `(1-2, 5-6 etc...)` as is, and replicate that setting to each new tab created? I hope I expressed my issue clearly.

Comment: By tab, you mean `sheet`. correct?

Comment: What is `1-2` supposed to be? Without knowing that, how are we to suggest a solution? Is `1-2` supposed to be a math operation (`-1`), a `month-day`, as in `1-2` means the second day of the first month, or something else?

Comment: @KenWhite I think he wants that formatted as Text. @user1905097 You could put that code to change the format to text in the `Worksheet_Change` event. But there must be a way to turn off that particular form of autoformatting from `Options>Proofing`.

Comment: @Cthulhu: I think so too, but the question isn't clear. I was asking for clarification of the question itself (like you where when asking about `sheet`). :-)

Comment: It's not a solution but a workaround: what if you created a macro that generates a new a sheet and changes the formatting of the desired columns (in VBA) and then add a shortcut/button to that Macro to your Quick Access Toolbar.  Instead of hitting "add sheet" hit your new button ...

Answer (score 3):

Copy the code into "Thisworkbook" section of your VBAProject:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Sh.Range("A1:C1000").NumberFormat = "@"
End Sub
```

The code is executed every time when a new worksheet is created, formatting its first 1000 rows in columns A:C as text.

Comment: with excel 2010, you can remove the numbers to convert the whole column, `Sh.Range("A:C").NumberFormat="@"`

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to use VBA? If you start a cell content with an apostrophe ( ' ) the content is considered to be text (by excel - no formating), and the apostrophe is not exibited, just the text after it. You can change your script to include the apostrophe.